# Create an odometer

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I tried to write a program here that adds one every time you click on the Step button. The problem I'm having is that every time i click Step, the digit is not incrementing at all. I think I'm supposed to put something in the actionListener block but I do not know what. Please help me...
If you think something is not clear, I'll clear it up really fast!

Panel

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Odometer extends JPanel{
   private JLabel label, label2, label3;
   private int counter;
   public Odometer()
   {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      JButton button = new JButton("Step");
      button.addActionListener(new Listener());
      add(button);

      this.setBackground(Color.black);

      label = new JLabel("0");
      label.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
      label.setForeground(Color.white);
      label.setBackground(Color.black);
      label.setOpaque(true);
      add(label);

      label2 = new JLabel("0");
      label2.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
      label2.setForeground(Color.white);
      label2.setBackground(Color.black);
      label2.setOpaque(true);
      add(label2);

      label3 = new JLabel("0");
      label3.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
      label3.setBackground(Color.white);
      label3.setForeground(Color.black);
      label3.setOpaque(true);
      add(label3);

      int counter = 0;
   }


   private class Listener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


      }

   }


   public void update()
   {
      counter = Integer.parseInt(label3.getText());
      if(counter < 9){
         counter++;
         label3.setText(" " + counter);

      }

      else{
         counter = 0;
         label3.setText(" " + counter);
         counter = Integer.parseInt(label2.getText());
         if(counter < 9){
            counter++;
            label2.setText(" " + counter);

         }
         else{
            counter = 0;
            label2.setText(" " + counter);
            counter = Integer.parseInt(label.getText());
         }
         if(counter<9){
            counter++;
            label.setText(" " + counter);
         }
         else{
            counter = 0;
            label.setText("0");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Driver

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
   public class Driver04
   {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Odometer");
         frame.setSize(400, 400);
         frame.setLocation(200, 100);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setContentPane(new Odometer());
         frame.setVisible(true);
      }
   }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to make it increment was change your code to:

`label3.setText("" + counter); //Empty String`

instead of

`label3.setText(" " + counter);`

Now that this is fixed, however your logic was still off.
Whenever the one's place went over the 9 threshold it would increment the tens place by one and hundreds place by two.

So what it looks like you did was you first did not put update in your listener as the person correctly identified in the earlier post but also you attempted to convert the number in the string incorrectly again correctly identified by the earlier post.

But the logic was off for several reasons 
Here is your update method

```
public void update()
   {
      counter = Integer.parseInt(label3.getText());
      if(counter < 9){
         counter++;
         label3.setText(" " + counter);

      }

      else{ //Correctly checks for larger than 9 in 1's place 
         counter = 0;
         label3.setText(" " + counter);
         counter = Integer.parseInt(label2.getText());
         if(counter < 9){
            counter++;
            label2.setText(" " + counter);

         }
         else{ //This is where code goes wrong
            counter = 0;
            label2.setText(" " + counter);
            counter = Integer.parseInt(label.getText());
         } < ---- This brace should be ...
         if(counter<9){
            counter++;
            label.setText(" " + counter);
         }
         else{
            counter = 0;
            label.setText("0");
         }
       <---- Right over here
      }
   }
}
```

The reason why that is wrong is because we should only check to increment the hundreds place only if there was a change in the 10's place that increments the 10's place from 9  to 10. With the code in its current state it keeps the counter as the same value as the 10 and increments by one.

When I ran your code with the update() called without the bug fix it would run as follows. 009 -> 210 instead of 010 for the explanation above.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Odometer extends JPanel{
   private JLabel label, label2, label3;
   private int counter;
   public Odometer()
   {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      JButton button = new JButton("Step");
      button.addActionListener(new Listener());
      add(button);

      this.setBackground(Color.black);

      label = new JLabel("0");
      label.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
      label.setForeground(Color.white);
      label.setBackground(Color.black);
      label.setOpaque(true);
      add(label);

      label2 = new JLabel("0");
      label2.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
      label2.setForeground(Color.white);
      label2.setBackground(Color.black);
      label2.setOpaque(true);
      add(label2);

      label3 = new JLabel("0");
      label3.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
      label3.setBackground(Color.white);
      label3.setForeground(Color.black);
      label3.setOpaque(true);
      add(label3);

   }


   private class Listener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          update();

      }

   }


   public void update()
   {

      counter = Integer.parseInt(label3.getText());
      if(counter < 9){
          System.out.println("increment");
         counter++;
         label3.setText("" + counter);

      }

      else{ //When the one's is greater than 9
         counter = 0;
         label3.setText("" + counter);
         counter = Integer.parseInt(label2.getText());


         if(counter < 9){ 
            counter++;
            label2.setText("" + counter);

         }
         else{ //When the 10's place is greater than 9
            counter = 0;
            label2.setText("" + counter);
            counter = Integer.parseInt(label.getText());

         if(counter<9){
            counter++;
            label.setText("" + counter);
         }
         else{ 
            counter = 0;
            label.setText("0");
            }
         }
      }


   }
}
```

*Just finished my errand so now I can explain your bug :).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your `update()` method in the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method. You should also have a closer look of the if else blocks you are using, may be you are missing something out.

Try using the code below (Odometer now implements ActionListener):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Odometer extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
   private JLabel label, label2, label3;
   private int counter;
   public Odometer()
   {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      int counter = 0;
      JButton button = new JButton("Step");
      button.addActionListener(this);
      add(button);

      this.setBackground(Color.black);

      label = new JLabel("0");
      label.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
      label.setForeground(Color.white);
      label.setBackground(Color.black);
      label.setOpaque(true);
      add(label);

      label2 = new JLabel("0");
      label2.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
      label2.setForeground(Color.white);
      label2.setBackground(Color.black);
      label2.setOpaque(true);
      add(label2);

      label3 = new JLabel("0");
      label3.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
      label3.setBackground(Color.white);
      label3.setForeground(Color.black);
      label3.setOpaque(true);
      add(label3);

   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      this.update();
   }


   public void update()
   {
      counter = Integer.parseInt(label3.getText());
      if(counter < 9){
         counter++;
         // removed " " + and set the string value of the counter to the label
         label3.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

      }

      else{
         counter = 0;
         label3.setText(counter);
         counter = Integer.parseInt(label2.getText());
         if(counter < 9){
            counter++;
            label2.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

         }
         else{
            counter = 0;
            label2.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            counter = Integer.parseInt(label.getText());
         }
         if(counter<9){
            counter++;
            label.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
         }
         else{
            counter = 0;
            label.setText("0");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that `" " +` is removed, so as to be able to parse the string into a number. We could also trim the empty space in the label text before parsing the string.

Below is a screenshot with no exceptions in the console:

[image: Odometer test screen]

Comment: thank you so very much! i tried the code and it lets me click the step button and it goes to one and but stops and gives me so many errors like "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1""

Comment: Just updated my code, `" " +` is removed, so as to be able to parse the string into a number. We could also trim the empty space in the label text before parsing the string.

Comment: how can we convert the int to a string if we rid of the'  " " + ' ?

Comment: By doing something like: `Integer.parseInt(label3.getText().trim());`. The trim() method of java.lang.String removes the trailing space characters in the beginning and end of the String.

Comment: it still doesn't increment after 1 even if i click step. can you please help me?